# What English homophone corresponds to 'oise salon'?

Tags: humor, puns

This is something of a fringe question. I hope it's considered on-topic.

There have been two books published which purport to be French poetry. The joke is that when read aloud, the poetry sounds, with some artistic license, like well-known English texts.

The first book is '*[Mots D'Heures: Gousses, Rames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mots_d%27Heures#Secondary_use)*', which 'translates' to 'Mother Goose rhymes'.

The other book is '*[Guillaume Chequespierre and the Oise Salon](https://www.librarything.com/work/1218503)*'. I can't work out what English phrase could be meant.

What is the English almost-homophone for 'Oise Salon'?

**EDIT:** From the front pages of the book. This lends credibility to mplungjan's answer.

[image: 13, Rue du Chat Mort]

Comment: 'Guillaume Chequespierre, and he was a loon?'.

Comment: Perhaps [*whistle on*](http://www.slang.ie/index.php?county=Cork&entry=whistle+on&letter=W), defined by someone there as Irish slang for *"Go away!"*, but understood by me as *"Dream on!", "In your dreams!" (i.e - "You can whistle for what you want, but you won't get it from me!"*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's also credible.

Comment: *"William Shakespeare and 'er Whistle On?"* - I dunno.

Comment: No. None of them sounds as convincing as 'Mother Goose Rhymes'. But surely one of them has to be it?

Comment: This question appears to be specifically off-topic because it falls in the category 'Jokes that do not rely on the English language'.

Comment: I don't understand the objection, Edwin. This is a play on English words, and question about a specific joke. It would not be possible in another language, although a similar joke could be made in another language.

Comment: Recommendation: Find and read a copy of the book in question. Odds are that the title story will use the phrase in a context that will help you determine the intended meaning. Trying to decode a deliberately obscured phrase _without_ context seems pointless.

Comment: It's on order, I will report back. The other title was so obvious that I thought this might also be.

Comment: The foreword to the book includes the note _There are few, if any, references to the Oise poets in the standard histories of French literature, and even the house in which they met, in the Rue du Chat Mort, is not marked out in any way, except by the Louis XIV pissoire which stands outside the door._

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would suggest "[Wazz](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/wazz) salon"

as in

> William Shakespeare and the Wazz Salon

- The pronunciation matches:

> From Wikipedia
>
> ***Oise*** (French pronunciation: ​[**waz**]) is a department in the north of France. It is named after the river Oise.

- The book is from Oct 1985

> **Wazz** - Urinate - 1980s: origin uncertain; perhaps an alteration of whizz.
>
> Source: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/wazz
>
> Whiz/Whizz
>
> sometimes vulgar :  an act of urinating —used especially in the phrase *take a whiz*
>
> Source: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whiz

- It is mentioned in this thesis:

> "This translator masquerades his traducsons as the original 
>   works of a school of French poets who meet regularly by a pissoir to recite their 
>   creations. The group is aptly called the “Oise Salon” (“**Wazz Salon**”) and calls a certain 
>   Guillaume Chequespierre its leader."
>
> Source: Sound Translation: Poetic and Cinematic Practices, Ryan Fraser

- and this review points out the pissoir

> The Oise Salon was located in front of the Louis XIV pissoir at 13 Rue de Chat Mort (#13 Dead Cat Street), Paris where a group of eccentric poets in the 1880's gathered to recite their works.
>
> Source: http://www.ivillage.com/forums/node/12881163#post-12881163

Note: Since I cannot find the text of the actual book online, the above two points are not verifiable

Comment: Fantastic, I had no idea the books had received any academic attention! But 'wizz' and 'wazz' aren't English words and those phrases don't make any sense (at least tome). Why would they be 'apt'?

Comment: Whizz is certainly English. See my update

Comment: I'd assumed that the 'translation' would be some kind of Standard English (I was aware of the American English slang but had discounted it). I the other suggestions of "was a loon" or "was alone" might be more likely?

Comment: Looks like it was published in Pennsylvania, so perhaps it's less far-fetched than I thought.   http://www.abebooks.com/Guillaume-Chequespierre-Oise-Salon-Anthology-Hulme/516135787/bd

Comment: *Wazz* is actually listed in OED.

Comment: So are many slang terms, I wouldn't call them Standard English necessarily. Anyway, I wasn't aware of either of those words in BrEng (which I assumed, perhaps wrongly, the book was). I have heard them in AmEng. I was talking about the *balance of likelihoods* of it being a word like that. The 'Mother Goose Rhymes' is a book about nursery rhymes and has a closely connected title. The 'Oise Salon' is a book about Shakespeare's plays, so I assumed it would have some connection to Shakespeare. I assume it has to have some meaning, I just find it hard to believe that this is it.

Comment: Please see my updates.

Comment: I think your last update is conclusive. It's been some years since I read the book, and I've ordered a copy (hence coming here to ask). I'll add any corroborating evidence! Thanks for all your efforts @mplungjan!

Comment: Typo: It's *Shakespeare* NOT *William Sharepeare*

Comment: @mplungjan The book arrived. Pictorial evidence added to the question backs up your hypothesis.

Comment: Haha. Cool. Very well then :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps *Once Alone* or *Was Alone*, both of which would suit the notion of an outhouse and how one finds oneself there.

Comment: _Guillaume Chequespierre and the Once Alone?_

Answer (score 0):

'Guillaume Chequespierre and the Oise Salon'=

William Shakespeare and he was alone.

Comment: no, I don't have sources. No, I shouldn't need them. If it's supposed to sound alike, this would make reasonable sense. Especially in light of the pronunciation of Mother.

Comment: That's one option certainly. I accepted mplungjan's answer because it seems to fit with the theme of the book (as per his last quote).

Comment: Certainly agree. Though it would be hard to argue against the William Shakespeare reference, right?

Comment: Sorry, don't understand. Which Shakespeare reference? Perhaps if 'the' had been spelt 'thé`. Maybe that's the joke. Mystery. The joke might be that it doesn't have a dual meaning after all. Who knows?

Comment: Guilaume Chequespierre = William Shakespeare.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I assumed that was a given.

Comment: I think this is the best option.